# updating tkinter label by sequential function call

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

i have a function with different argument,depending upon argument my tkinter label should update automatically as i am passing argument on sequential method like one after another::
here is my code.

```
import time
import Tkinter as tk

i='*00T%'
j='*01T%'
def read(n):
    if n=='*00T%':
        print('hi')
        value = 1
        value += 1
        var1.set(value)
    elif n=='*01T%':
        print('hello')
        value = 6
        value += 1
        var2.set(value)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("serial recieved values ")
var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()
label1 = tk.Label(root,bg='gold',fg='blue', textvariable=var1)
label2 = tk.Label(root,bg='gold',fg='blue', textvariable=var2)
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
read,(i, )
time.sleep(0.5)
read,(j, )
time.sleep(0.5)
root.after(1000,read(i))
root.after(1000,read(j))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand when your Label are supposed to be updated. Here is a modified version of your code where the Labels are updated alternatively, every 500 ms. Does that look like what you need?

```
import tkinter as tk

i='*00T%'
j='*01T%'

def read(n):
    if n == i:
        var1.set(var1.get()+1) # update var1
        root.after(500, lambda:read(j)) # recall function in 500 ms
    elif n == j:
        var2.set(var2.get()+1) # update varé
        root.after(500, lambda:read(i)) # recall function in 500 ms

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("serial received values")

var1 = tk.IntVar()
var1.set(1) # initial value for var1
var2 = tk.IntVar()
var2.set(6) # initial value for var2

label1 = tk.Label(root, bg='gold', fg='blue', textvariable=var1)
label1.pack()
label2 = tk.Label(root, bg='gold', fg='blue', textvariable=var2)
label2.pack()

root.after(500, lambda:read(i))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ..from your valuable idea i got solution for my code.

Answer (score -1):

i want to update my label continuously and read  serial connected  devices values..
for that this basic idea of code working ..tested and trailed with hardware.
note that this is a idea code not the code of serial.
but from this idea we can handle multiple slave connected on same serial port on rs-485 protocol for read and write operation.

```
import serial
import time
import Tkinter as tk
i='*00T%'
j='*01T%'
value=0
value1=5
def read():
    global value
    print('hi')
    value += 1
    var1.set(value)
def read1():
    global value1
    print('hello')
    value1 += 1
    var2.set(value1)
def choose():
        read()#1st read function execute
        time.sleep(1)
        read1()#next read1 function execute
        time.sleep(1)
        root.after(1000,choose)#for continuous label update 

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("serial recieved values ")
var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()
label1 = tk.Label(root,bg='gold',fg='blue', textvariable=var1)
label2 = tk.Label(root,bg='gold',fg='blue', textvariable=var2)
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
root.after(1000,choose)
root.mainloop()
```